# Match reps of same number

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of phone numbers and I want to be able to tell if a number looks "funny". By that I mean, a number that has repeated numbers. For example:

```
822222222
822333444
822222999
```

Basically, 822 + two sets of three numbers that are the same.

I'm doing this with JAVA and so far I have this:

```
if (number.matches("^((822|654|611)\\d{3}\\d{3})$"))
```

which obviously matches those numbers but it also matches:

```
822315487
```

which is not a special number. (Don't pay attention to the 654 and 611 numbers, I  need to consider those too.)

How can I go about this? How do I construct a regex that matches the same number 3 times?

Comment: I really do not understand what a *funny* number is. Can you give more examples, and *limit* examples?

Comment: @sp00m numbers that have repeated numbers are "funny" and people want them as their phone numbers. More examples: 822111999 822000111 822333444 822666111. Normal numbers (not-funny): 822147877 822114785 822112255 (although this last one is funny to me, it doesn't fit the requirement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following for the final six digits:

```
(000|111|222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999){2}
```

Comment: Yup, I thought about this but is this the cleanest way?

Comment: To my eye this looks pretty clean, if slightly verbose.

Comment: It will match `822111444` too, for example. But maybe this is also a *funny* number...

Comment: @NPE what if I want three repetitions of two equal numbers? I thought: (00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99){2}{2} but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @NPE definitely meant (00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99){3}

Answer (score 5):

The core problem is that `\d` matches any digit, so you are saying 3x of any digit, not 3x of the same digit. So you need to capture that digit, then repeat it two times.

```
^822(\d)\1{2}(\d)\2{2}$
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the Java regular expression implementation... hopefully someone else can chime in.